# First book in a series that ends with an army exiting a portal in a mountain

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember the book ended when they traveled to a mountain and there saw an army of the enemy coming out of a portal. That was the ending of book one.

I believe the enemy had some sort of spider-like things, probably made of metal and they could have been powered by the gems. I don't remember if they were the things themselves, or rode them.

The book started with a girl living in some city; I believe they were mining or discovering, or charging some sort of crystals and then the enemy attacked - but not an army, just a few, so she had to escape.

I believe they got to the mountain in some sort of airship, but I am not certain if this was my imagination or really part of the story.

I must have read it 10 to 20 years ago. I would love to reread it again, and the whole series, but I can't remember the name. At the time, I had taken it from my library and didn't have the money to buy the second part, which my library did not carry.

Comment: This sounds like one of the DOOM books maybe?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: @nikolow - Looks like you're now using a different account than the one you used to post this question, which means you can no longer edit the question, leave comments beneath it, or mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can regain the ability to do all these things by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.